# How can we get the total letters which is input by a user(say "aryan" , this contains "5" words) only using for() and range() function?

Tags: python

```py
name = input("Name: ")

for i in range(len(name)):
  last = i.index[-1]
  print(last)
```

This shows that `int` doesn't have this attribute. Then how can I just print the number of letters containing from the input(Ex: above as `5`)

Comment: `print(len(name))`

Comment: If the goal is to avoid the use of `len`, you could do it through incrementing a variable, attempting to access an index and then catching an `IndexError` exception with a `for` loop with a very large `range` (if you can't use a while loop). But if you only want the length, use `len` directly since you're already using it in your `range` call.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```py
name = input("Name: ")
print(len(name))
```

but if you are restricted to only `for` and `range` then:

```py
name = input("Name: ")
counter = 0
for i in name:
    counter +=1
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `len(name)` in your code. That is just the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is use `len`.

```
print(len(name))
```

If you are not allowed to use that function, you could use a loop that increments a counter and removes the first character of the string on each iteration until the string is empty.

```
name = input("Name: ")
chars = 0
while name:
    chars += 1
    name = name[1:]
print(chars)
```